# Generate tables with unique names

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb

I need to create non-temporary tables in a MariaDB 10.3 database using Node. I therefore need a way of generating a table name that is guaranteed to be unique.

The Node function cannot access information regarding any unique feature about what or when the tables are made, so I cannot build the name from a timestamp or connection ID. I can only verify the name's uniqueness using the current database.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001980/sql-generate-unique-table-view-name) had a PostgreSQL answer suggesting the following:

```
SET @name = GetBigRandomNumber();

WHILE TableExists(@name)
BEGIN
    SET @name = GetBigRandomNumber();
END
```

I attempted a MariaDB implementation using `@name = CONCAT(MD5(RAND()),MD5(RAND()))` to generate a random 64 character string, and `(COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @name) >0` to check if it was a unique name:

```
SET @name = CONCAT(MD5(RAND()),MD5(RAND()));
WHILE ((COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @name) >0) DO
    SET @name = CONCAT(MD5(RAND()),MD5(RAND()));
END WHILE;
CREATE TABLE @name ( ... );
```

However I get a syntax error when I try to run the above query. My SQL knowledge isn't that great so I'm at a loss as to what the problem might be.

Furthermore, is this approach efficient? The randomly generated name is long enough that it is very unlikely to have any clashes with any current table in the database, so the `WHILE` loop will very rarely need to run, but is there some sort of built in function to auto increment table names, or something similar?

Comment: . . The need to generate random table names seems like a real problem with the data model used by your application.  I suspect you may have deeper issues.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that may well be the case. The app allows users to create and collaborate on projects. I am storing each project in a separate table; thus when a user creates a new project the corresponding table must have a unique name. (to be honest I _could_ combine the user's ID and timestamp for a unique name but I would like to see if I can achieve this with SQL only). This might be a bad model to use - I have not had much experience with databases so with my limited knowledge it's what made sense when designing the concept.

Comment: . . These should all be rows in a single table.  If you have security requirements -- where user data is required to be physically separated from other users -- then you should be using separate databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you, very helpful! May I ask: why is it a better model to have them all in one table? Efficiency?

Comment: Performance, maintainability, security, and analytic efficiency all come to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @name := UUID();
```

If the dashes in that cause trouble, then

```
SET @name := REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '');
```

It will be safer (toward uniqueness) than `RAND()`.  And, in theory, there will be no need to verify its uniqueness.  After all, that's the purpose of UUIDs.

Comment: I ended up restructuring my data mode to use a single table as @GordonLinoff suggested, but this seems to be a very elegant solution to the original problem.